# Nginx inside pod responds with "400 Bad request" if coming from nginx ingress. Directly from pod it works fine

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress

Help will be much appreciated.

We have forced to upgrade our dockers to ubuntu18.04 from ubuntu16.04 becuase php7.3 is no longer supported using PPA.

After the upgrade we got "400 Bad request" errors from nginx inside the pod. The new nginx version is 1.18 (previous on ubuntu16.04 was 1.16.1).

I've tried to access the pod using ssh and run curl, and it works fine. It also works fine if I curl pod from another pod on the cluster. But it responds with 400 if coming from the nginx ingress (AWS LB).

I've spent a lot of time googling, trying to figure out what the issue is . If you have encountered that , I'll be happy to hear some advice.

Thanks!!

Comment: What if you expose other services in the same ingress, are they reachable? The 400 is return by the ingress or by the nginx pod ?

Comment: The 400 returned by the nginx pod (1.18) , only if coming through ingress . 
Older pod with nginx 1.16.1 - same everything - works fine from both ingress and direct

Comment: Please provide more details so that your issue can be easily reproduced. Anything in nginx-ingress controller logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem just disappeared. we have deployed again after a few days and everything works. not sure what happened

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following annotations to the ingress.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
```